# .htaccess redirect only if GET parameter exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I have the following line in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Redirect 301 /folder1 https://www.example.com/folder2/file.php
```

This will redirect everything from `/folder1` to `https://www.example.com/folder2/file.php`.

I need a condition to only allow this redirection if the URL contains a `mykey=` GET parameter, else ignore this redirection command.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using `Redirect` directive that does basic URI matching.

You will need to use `mod_rewrite` based rules for this like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mykey= [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder1(/|$) /folder2/file.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your cache before testing.

**References:**

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the a working solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder1/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mykey=
RewriteRule ^folder1\/$ /folder2/file.php$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ah I just noted your own answer. There is no `$1` here and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ` can be removed